# Repair Reactive Armor in BF4 like in BF3?

Tags: battlefield-4

How do I do it in Battlefield 4 i tried it. I could do it in Battlefield 3.

Comment: To be honest I don't believe you can. I was under the impression that being able to do that in BF3 was a glitch that turned into a feature.

Answer (score 2):

Reactive armor works very differently in BF4 than in BF3, and you can't repair reactive armor in BF4.